# Slow cascade delete on rows referenced from a partitioned table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-partitioning

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE events (
    id bigserial not null
            constraint birth_events _pkey
                primary key
) 

CREATE TABLE birth_events (
    simulation_id integer not null,
    event_id integer not null
            constraint fk_event_id
                references public.events
                    on update cascade on delete cascade
) PARTITION BY LIST (simulation_id);

create index ix_birth_events_event_id
    on public.birth_events (event_id);
```

`birth_events` is a partitioned table (using declarative partitioning) with `simulation_id` being the partition key. It has hundred of partitions containing thousands of rows each. Deleting from table `events` (thousands of rows at the same time) is super slow because PostgreSQL will scan the foreign key index of each `birth_events` partitions individually so it can cascade delete them. I would like to tell PostgreSQL to limit its cascade deletion of `birth_events` on a specific `simulation_id` so it only scans one partition, but how do I do this in SQL?

```
DELETE FROM events
LEFT JOIN birth_events on events.id = birth_events.event_id
WHERE events.id IN (XXX) AND birth_events.simulation_id = XXX;
```

This would tell PostgreSQL to look only a specific table partition, but it is not valid SQL. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Done. The statement was simplified to focus on the problem, hence these 2 mistakes were introduced.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an EXISTS condition:

```
delete from events
where events.id in (....)
  and exists (select * 
              from birth_events 
              where birth_events.simulation_id = 123456
                and birth_events.event_id = events.id);
```

Or maybe the USING clause:

```
delete from events
  using birth_events 
where events.id in (....)
  and birth_events.simulation_id = 123456
  and birth_events.event_id = events.id
```

Whether or not that uses partition pruning depends on the Postgres version. I doubt it would happen on Postgres 10 or 11.

On Postgres 14, both result in the same execution plan and I can see only the partition for the specified simulation_id being scanned.